# Sorting an array consisting binary numbers in java

Tags: java, arrays, binary

What i want is that i want to sort an array which consists of binary numbers i.e {0,01,001,110,1} then the answer after sorting should be {0,1,01,001,110} in java.It must also be sorted according to length.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having with your current solution?

Comment: Yes sir, i tried it but it couldn't sort binary numbers e.g. if i take 01 then it considers it as 1 only.

Comment: @SanchitShah - you are representing binary numbers as String right?. becaause `01` is an octal number and different from `1`

Comment: I don't really see a problem with this question... Maybe not interesting to some with more experience, but that's not a good close reason.

Comment: @TheLostMind `01` is different from `1`??? Maybe `010` is different from `10`, but...

Comment: Can you confirm that you want to sort on length *first*, and then on value?

Comment: The problem is that there is not a primary type that represents a binary number where each binary number has a specific set of bits. You would need to either generate a special class for that (`BitSet` won't work), or you would have to use another representation such as a `String` as Chris suggests.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is not really sorting of binary numbers. I'm guessing your array is a String array?

You could just implement a Comparator that first compares the length of the strings and if they are equal, convert the number to byte or integer and compare the values.

---

Code example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class BinaryStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // check input
        if (!o1.matches("[01]*") || !o2.matches("[01]*")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only strings representing binary values are allowed");
        }

        // compare lengths first
        if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
            return 1;
        }

        // compare values if the length is equal
        final int i1 = Integer.parseInt(o1, 2);
        final int i2 = Integer.parseInt(o2, 2);
        return Integer.compare(i1, i2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // input was {0,01,001,110,1}
        String[] input = { "0", "01", "001", "110", "1" };
        Arrays.sort(input, new BinaryStringComparator());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Chris and +1. You may get more upvotes with a small example.

Comment: Of course you can also first compare the value, and then the length, I'll leave it as an exercise to do that.